# Symmetric difference of two sets in Java

Tags: java, collections, set

There are two `TreeSet`s in my app:

```
set1 = {501,502,503,504}
set2 = {502,503,504,505}
```

I want to get the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of these sets so that my output would be the set:

```
set = {501,505}
```

Comment: +1 for explaining _exactly_ what you want to get out.

Comment: This is not set subtraction. `set1 - set2` would be all elements in `set1` but not in `set2`, i.e. `{501}`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're after the [symmetric difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmetricDifference.html). This is discussed in the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html).

```
Set<Type> symmetricDiff = new HashSet<Type>(set1);
symmetricDiff.addAll(set2);
// symmetricDiff now contains the union
Set<Type> tmp = new HashSet<Type>(set1);
tmp.retainAll(set2);
// tmp now contains the intersection
symmetricDiff.removeAll(tmp);
// union minus intersection equals symmetric-difference
```

Answer (score 12):

You could use [`CollectionUtils#disjunction`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#disjunction(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable))

EDIT:

Alternatively with less pre-Java-5-ness, use Guava [Sets#symmetricDifference](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#symmetricDifference-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-)

Comment: I hate the whole pre-Java5-ness of those Apache commons libs, but it's certainly a viable option.

Answer (score 3):

use retain all,remove all then addAll to do a union of existing set.

> 1. intersectionSet.retainAll(set2) // intersectionSet is a copy of set1
> 2. set1.addAll(set2); // do a union of set1 and set2
> 3. then remove the duplicates set1.removeAll(intersectionSet);

Answer (score 3):

Those looking for [set subtraction/complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) (not symmetric difference/disjunction) can use [`CollectionUtils.subtract(a,b)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#subtract%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) or [`Sets.difference(a,b)`](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>();
    s1.add("a");
    s1.add("b");
    s2.add("b");
    s2.add("c");
    Set<String> s3 = new HashSet<String>(s1);
    s1.removeAll(s2);
    s2.removeAll(s3);
    s1.addAll(s2);
    System.out.println(s1);
```

output of s1 : [a,c]

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Sets.symmetricDifference()` from [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

```
Set<Integer> set1 = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(501,502,503,504));
Set<Integer> set2 = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(502,503,504,505));
Set<Integer> symmetricDifference =
        Sets.symmetricDifference(set1, set2);

Assert.assertEquals(
        new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(501, 505)),
        symmetricDifference);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

if we use package com.google.common.collect, we may ellegantly find symmetric difference like this :

```
    Set<Integer> s1 = Stream.of( 1,2,3,4,5 ).collect( Collectors.toSet());
    Set<Integer> s2 = Stream.of( 2,3,4 ).collect( Collectors.toSet());
    System.err.println(Sets.symmetricDifference( s1,s2 ));
```

The output will be : 
[1, 5]